# KeyError when searching for items in dict inventory

Tags: python, class, dictionary

Over the past few months I've been attempting to create a text-based Zork-style game as a project to teach myself Python.

Thanks to the wonderful people here at stackoverflow and plenty of youtube video's, I've made decent progress. The issue I'm currently dealing with is towards the bottom of the code, in the Bag class. 
As you will see below in my bag class, I have a method called Take. This method originally was not within the bag class, it was in the section at the bottom that reads user commands.

```
class Bag:

    def __init__(self, inventory):
        self.inventory = inventory

    def addToInventory(self, item):
        for key in list(Location.room.roominv.keys()):
            self.inventory.append(Location.room.roominv[key])
            del Location.room.roominv[key]

    def SearchRoom(self):
        if Location.room.roominv:
            for item in list(Location.room.roominv.keys()):
                print("you find a", item)
        else:
            print("You don't find anything")

    def NoneHere(self, command):
        print("You can't find a", command)

    def Take(self, command):
        for key in list(Location.room.roominv.keys()):
            if Location.room.roominv[key].name == command.split()[1]:
                bag.addToInventory(key)
                print('you take the', key)

    def CheckTake(self):
        if Location.room.roominv and command.split()[1] in Location.room.roominv:
            self.Take(command)
        else:
            self.NoneHere(command.split()[1])

    def CheckInv(self):
        for item in list(bag.inventory):
            print("Your bag contains:", item.name)


player = Player("Jeff", 100)
bag = Bag([])
Location = Location('introd')

command = '  '
while command != "":
    command = input('>>> ')
    if command in Location.room.exits:
        Location.travel(command)
    elif command == 'look':
        Location.RoomDesc()
    elif command == '':
        print('You have to say what it is you want to do!')
        command = '#'
    elif command == 'search':
        bag.SearchRoom()
    elif command.split()[0] == 'Take':
        bag.CheckTake()
    elif command == 'Inventory':
        bag.CheckInv()
    else:
        print('Invalid command')
```

I was advised to separate the logic of user commands from the rest of the game so I moved it to a specified class.

Before I did this however, the game would have no problem picking up only specific items from a rooms inventory. Now it picks up all.

(Code defining each room will be posted at bottom, I've been importing it from a separate .py file)

Currently, only one of my rooms contains more than one Item. The "inside cottage" room, which contains "Ornate_Key" and "Knife".

Here's the strange thing. If I try to take the Ornate_Key, it picks it up fine (Also picks up the Knife though).

However if I try to take the Knife, I receive an error with this traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Daniel/Python 3.6/Scripts/PythonPR/Flubbo'sModuleTest.py", line 156, in <module>
    bag.CheckTake()
  File "C:/Users/Daniel/Python 3.6/Scripts/PythonPR/Flubbo'sModuleTest.py", line 130, in CheckTake
    self.Take(command)
  File "C:/Users/Daniel/Python 3.6/Scripts/PythonPR/Flubbo'sModuleTest.py", line 122, in Take
    if Location.room.roominv[key].name == command.split()[1]:
KeyError: 'Ornate_Key'
```

I've spent about 6 hours tinkering with this code, going back to older versions and comparing this current one to ones where I wasn't hitting this issue, and I can't figure out why this suddenly started happening.

I am very new to coding in general, so I'm very fuzzy on architecture/the fundamentals of things. Does anyone have any idea what is causing this issue?

At the very bottom of this page I will post a section of code from an older version that is not experiencing this problem.

Considering this post is already very long, I might as well post an example game to demonstrate exactly what is happening.

```
    >>> look
You are in a forest, you can hear wildlife all around you. There seems to be a clearing in the distance.
{'Search the ground', 'Go North'}
>>> search
you find a Sword
>>> Take Sword
you take the Sword
>>> n
moving to clearing
You are in a clearing surrounded by forest. Sunlight is streaming in, illuminating a bright white flower in the center of the clearing. To the South is the way you entered the forest. A well worn path goes to the East. In the distance a harp can be heard.
{'Go East', 'Take flower', 'Go south'}
>>> e
moving to forest path
You begin walking down a well beaten path. The sounds of the forest surround you. Ahead you can see a fork in the road branching to the South and East.You can smell smoke coming from the South, and can hear a stream to the East
{'Go East', 'Go West', 'Go South'}
>>> e
moving to stream
You come upon a relaxing stream at the edge of the woods. It looks like there is something shiny in the water. To your South is a rickety looking shack, to your West is the forest path you came down
{'Go West', 'Go South'}
>>> Take Rusty_Key
you take the Rusty_Key
>>> s
moving to shack
In front of you is a shack, possibly used as an outpost for hunting. It looks dilapidated.
{'Go North', 'Go South'}
>>> s
moving to inside shack
The inside of the shack is dirty. Bits of ragged fur are scattered about the floor and on a table against the back wall.A sharp looking knife is on the table. There is an ornate key hanging on the wall by a string.
{'Take Key', 'Take Knife', 'Go North'}
>>> search
you find a Knife
you find a Ornate_Key
>>> Take Ornate_Key
you take the Ornate_Key
>>> Inventory
Your bag contains: Sword
Your bag contains: Rusty_Key
Your bag contains: Knife
Your bag contains: Ornate_Key
>>>
```

Comment: Sorry but this is waaay too long. Can you boil it down to the minimal example to illustrate the issue? The fact that this is a Zork-based game, for example, is irrelevant to the functioning of python classes

Comment: Also, if you're trying new constructs in python, it would be much easier to prototype the basic functionality before applying to your problem. If your approach is fundamentally flawed but it runs throughout your entire project before you realise it doesn't work, that's a hell of a lot of stuff to fix/undo

Comment: I'll attempt to edit it for length now. As far as prototyping the basic functionality, as I said, this was working in an earlier version of my code. I'm not sure why the functionality has changed now that it is contained within a class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any particular reason why you have a `Take` method in `Bag`? It seems totally redundant, considering all you want to do is add that item if it exists in a dictionary. Try this:

```
def CheckTake(self):
    key = command.split()[1]
    if Location.room.roominv and key in Location.room.roominv:
        bag.addToInventory(key)
        print('you take the', key)
    else:
        self.NoneHere(key)
```

Also, your code is inconsistent. In some places, you access globals directly, while in other places, you redundantly pass it to a function. I would strongly advice you to take this to [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) and get your act together once you get this working.

Comment: I actually posted an earlier version of this code in code review and was advised to split up my functions more, I may have gone a bit overboard with that. 

 Also, thank you! I knew it was redundant but couldn't figure out how to get rid of it. key = command.split()[1] was the answer.


Could you give an example of spots where I am sometimes accessing globals directly while in others passing it to a function?

 I really am teaching myself from scratch here and things like that are what I'm getting tripped up on.

Comment: @Schrodinger'sStat Yep. You certainly have code smell. Nothing unsalvageable, but your code could use some TLC... that's for sure. Anyway, feel free to try this out. If it works, feel free to ^vote/mark accepted.

Comment: @Schrodinger'sStat For example `CheckTake` treats `command` as global, but `Take` receives it as a param.

Comment: Solved the problem! removed

"key in list(Location.room.roominv.keys()):"

 from my addToInventory function. Now off to code review to clean up further issues like that.

Comment: @Schrodinger'sStat All the best.